# Decidable languages unconditionally not in P/poly

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

What are some nice/natural examples of languages not contained in $P/\mathit{poly}$, preferably decidable ones?

I'm interested in *unconditional* results rather than examples such as the Karp–Lipton theorem, which states that SAT is not in $P/\mathit{poly}$ unless the polynomial hierarchy collapses.

Comment: Perhaps a visit to the [complexity zoo](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppoly) gives you the chance to spot a few nice animals.

Comment: Do you want languages that are unconditionally outside $P\setminus \mathit{poly}$? Or do you allow languages that are outside of it under certain complexity assumptions?

Comment: @Discrete lizard I would prefer unconditionally. Honestly, looking at the zoo did not help me this time.

Comment: The halting problem requires exponential size circuits, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/115286/7732.

Comment: The same answer also states that there are computable functions having the maximum possible circuit complexity, but they might not be nice/natural.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Thank you for the answers! I am still wondering if there is a computable example outside P/poly that can be "nicely" defined.

Comment: @Adelhart Can you [edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/144850/edit) your question in order to add the additional information you mentioned in the comments? There's no need to do an "EDIT:" btw, we keep the history of your question, so just write an improved version of your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H_{f(n)}$ be the set of all pairs $(M,x)$ such that $M$ halts on $x$ within $f(|x|)$ steps. We encode the pairs in such a way that $|(M,x)| = |x| + C_M$, where $C_M$ is a constant that depends only on $M$. Suppose that $H_{f(n)}$ has circuits of size $g(n)$ (note that it's a slightly different $n$).

Let $h(n) \leq \kappa 2^n/n$, for an appropriate $\kappa > 0$.
Let $M_{h(n)}$ be the Turing machine which on input $x$ of length $n$ generates all $n$-input circuits of size at most $h(n)$, determines the lexicographically first truth table of an $n$-bit function $\Phi_{n,h(n)}$ which is not generated by this circuit (such a function exists due to our assumption on $h(n)$), halts if $\Phi_{n,h(n)}(x) = 1$, and enters an infinite loop otherwise. By construction, $\Phi_{n,h(n)}$ cannot be computed by a circuit of size $h(n)$ or less.

The running time of $M_{h(n)}$ on an input of length $n$ is $O(2^{h(n) + n})$, hence if we choose $f(n) \geq K 2^{h(n) + n}$ for an appropriate constant $K > 0$, we can compute $\Phi_{n,h(n)}$ using a circuit of size $g(n + C_{M_{h(n)}}) + O(1)$. This shows that for some constant $C>0$, $g(n + C_{M_{h(n)}}) + C > h(n)$.

Given $f(n)$, the best choice for $h(n)$ is $\min(\log_2 f(n) - n - K',\kappa 2^n/n)$, where $K'$ is some constant. This implies the following result, which holds for some constant $C'$.

**Theorem.** Suppose that for all $D>0$ there exists $n$ such that $\min(f(n),2^{\kappa 2^n/n}) \geq 2^{g(n + D) + n + C'}$. Then $H_{f(n)}$ cannot be computed by circuits of size $g(n)$ or smaller.

In particular, $H_{2^{r(n)}}$ doesn't have polynomial size circuits whenever $r(n)$ is super-polynomial. On the other hand, $H_{2^{r(n)}}$ can be computed in time roughly $O(2^{r(n)})$.

(This is essentially the argument of Jeřábek in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/115286/7732).)